# MySQL Group by complex script

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have an script that works perfect, but need to add values from another table
Current script is

```
    select v.id, vm.producto_id, sum(vm.total), count(v.id)
from visita v, reporte r, visitamaquina vm, maquina m, 
(select r.id, empleado_id, fecha, cliente_id from ruta r, rutacliente rc where r.id=rc.ruta_id and 
fecha>='2016-10-01' and fecha<='2016-10-30' group by fecha, cliente_id, empleado_id) as rem
where rem.fecha=v.fecha and v.cliente_Id=rem.cliente_id and r.visita_id=v.id and vm.visita_id=v.id and m.id=vm.maquina_id
group by vm.visita_id, vm.producto_id
```

Current Script returns this (I need some extra columns but for this purpose I only leave the ones with issues):

```
| Producto_Id   |        Id    | Total     | count(id) |
|---------------|--------------|-----------|-----------|
|          1    |          31  |        21 |     2     |
|          2    |          31  |        15 |     3     |
|          3    |          31  |        18 |     2     |
```

Table VisitaMaquina has multiple records for same producto_id
VisitaMaquina has this:

```
| Producto_Id   | Visita_Id    | Total     |
|---------------|--------------|-----------|
|          1    |          31  |        8  |
|          1    |          31  |        13 |
|          2    |          31  |        9  |
```

Same situation happens with table called reporteproducto, where multiple times producto_id is repeated.

Table reporteproducto has

```
| Producto_Id   | Visita_Id    | Quantity  |
|---------------|--------------|-----------|
|          1    |          31  |         4 |
|          1    |          31  |         7 |
|          2    |          31  |         5 |
```

My previous query works fine, and I just need to get the sum of quantity

I used this Script and this is what I got

```
    select v.id, vm.producto_id, sum(vm.total), sum(quantity), count(id)
from visita v, reporte r, visitamaquina vm, maquina m, reporteproducto rp,
(select r.id, empleado_id, fecha, cliente_id from ruta r, rutacliente rc where r.id=rc.ruta_id and 
fecha>='2016-10-01' and fecha<='2016-10-30' group by fecha, cliente_id, empleado_id) as rem
where rem.fecha=v.fecha and v.cliente_Id=rem.cliente_id and r.visita_id=v.id and vm.visita_id=v.id and m.id=vm.maquina_id and rp.visita_Id=v.id and rp.producto_id=vm.producto_id
group by vm.visita_id, vm.producto_id
```

I got this

```
|Producto_Id    | Visita_Id    | Total     |Quantity   | count(id)
|---------------|--------------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
|          1    |          31  |        42 |      11   |     4     |
|          2    |          31  |        45 |      18   |     6     |
|          3    |          31  |        36 |      44   |     4     |
```

The desired result is (focus on producto_id=1):

```
|Producto_Id    | Visita_Id    | Total     |Quantity   |
|---------------|--------------|-----------|-----------|
|          1    |          31  |        21 |      11   |
|          2    |          31  |        15 |      18   |
|          3    |          31  |        18 |      44   |
```

Any Idea on how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better group the sub table that has multiple data with the same group of your outer group by columns.In your case the `VisitaMaquina` and `reporteproducto` should be group by with `visita_id, producto_id` since they all have repeat rows with the same combination of `vid=31 and pid=1`.

You can change the `visitamaquina vm` and `reporteproducto rp` table alias to sub query form of the following:

```
(select visita_id, Producto_Id, sum(Total) as Total from visitamaquina 
 group by visita_id, Producto_Id) vm,  
(select Producto_Id, Visita_Id, sum(Quantity) as Quantity from reporteproducto
 group by Producto_Id, Visita_Id) rp
```

Also I found that there is `vm.maquina_id` in your where clause, maybe this causes your problem.Because if the `visitamaquina` and `reporteproducto` both have repeat values of `visita_id, producto_id` then the output should have `Total, Quantity` both doubled.In your output the `Quantity` is right, that's odd.

Comment: It is a good option, just that visitamaquina and reporteproducto have more than 1,000,000 records and I need to add a filter based on another table

Comment: @GerardoAbdo still cant figure out why the `total` is doubled and the `quantity` is right.

Comment: I used your suggested script and seems to be the best option from now.  Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

My Mistake

I got this

```
|Producto_Id    | Visita_Id    | Total     |Quantity   | count(id)
|---------------|--------------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
|          1    |          31  |        42 |      22   |     4     |
|          2    |          31  |        45 |      36   |     6     |
|          3    |          31  |        36 |      88   |     4     |
```